# I am tryin to to a row echelon reduction code (not reduced row echelon) I have a working code but i am trying to clean up the for loops

Tags: c++

this is the code that is have i am trying to get the take the for loops that i have and condense them
into a loop but i am not sure how. If there is anyone that can help me out i would appreciate it. The fist set of for loops are taking the inverse and then it is muiltiplying through the positions of the array. Right now the for loops are going through on position for each loop and i know there is a better way but i cant think of how to do it.

```
 using namespace std;
        #include<iostream>
        #include<fstream>
        #include<iomanip>
        #include<Windows.h>
    
        // User-defined function declarations (prototypes)
        void readit();
        void calcit(float[5][6], float[5][6]);
        void writeit(float [5][6], float[5][6], float[5]);
        
        // Declaration and definition of the main()
        int main()
        {
            readit();
            
            return 0;
        }
        
        void readit()
        {
            // Local variable declarations
            float origarray[5][6], reducedarray[5][6];
            
            // Filestream declaration and error trap
            ifstream infile("C:\\EGR111\\rowechelondata.txt");
            
            if(!infile)
            {
                cout << "There is no file, or the filestream is corrupted. Correct the problem and "
                     << "try again!";
                     
                Sleep(2000);
                exit(0);
            }
            
            // File read. 'i' is row index and 'j' is column index. 
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    infile >> origarray[i][j];
                    reducedarray[i][j] = origarray[i][j];
                }
            }
            
            calcit(origarray, reducedarray);
        }
        
        void calcit(float origarray[5][6], float reducedarray[5][6])
        {
            // Local variable declaration
            float roots[5] = {};
            
            cout << setprecision(4) << endl;
            // Multiply first row by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'
            for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) 
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = origarray[i][j] * (1.0 / origarray[0][0]);
                }
            }
            // Multiply second row by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'
            for(int i = 1; i < 2; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) 
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = origarray[i][j] * (1.0 / origarray[1][0]);
                }
            }
            // Multiply third row by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'
            for(int i = 2; i < 3; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) 
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = origarray[i][j] * (1.0 / origarray[2][0]);
                }
            }
            // Multiply fourth row by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'      
            for(int i = 3; i < 4; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = origarray[i][j] * (1.0 / origarray[3][0]);
                }
            }
            // Multiply fifth row by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'
            for(int i = 4; i < 5; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) 
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = origarray[i][j] * (1.0 / origarray[4][0]);
                }
            }
            // Subtract the first row of the reduced array into the subsequent rows 
            for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = reducedarray[i][j] - reducedarray[0][j];
                }
            }
            // Multiply array position [1][1] by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'
            for(int i = 1; i < 2; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 1; j < 6; j++) 
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = reducedarray[i][j] * (1.0 / reducedarray[1][1]);
                }
            }
            // Multiply array position [2][1] by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'
            for(int i = 2; i < 3; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 1; j < 6; j++) 
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = reducedarray[i][j] * (1.0 / reducedarray[2][1]);
                }
            }
            // Multiply array position [3][1] by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'
            for(int i = 3; i < 4; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 1; j < 6; j++) 
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = reducedarray[i][j] * (1.0 / reducedarray[3][1]);
                }
            }
            // Multiply array position [4][1] by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'
            for(int i = 4; i < 5; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 1; j < 6; j++) 
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = reducedarray[i][j] * (1.0 / reducedarray[4][1]);
                }
            }
            // Subtract the second row of the reduced array into the subsequent rows    
            for(int i = 2; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 1; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = reducedarray[i][j] - reducedarray[1][j];
                }
            }
            // Multiply array position [2][2] by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'
            for(int i = 2; i < 3; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 2; j < 6; j++) 
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = reducedarray[i][j] * (1.0 / reducedarray[2][2]);
                }
            }    
            // Multiply array position [3][2] by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'
            for(int i = 3; i < 4; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 2; j < 6; j++) 
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = reducedarray[i][j] * (1.0 / reducedarray[3][2]);
                }
            }
            // Multiply array position [4][2] by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'
            for(int i = 4; i < 5; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 2; j < 6; j++) 
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = reducedarray[i][j] * (1.0 / reducedarray[4][2]);
                }
            }    
            // Subtract the third row of the reduced array into the subsequent rows 
            for(int i = 3; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 2; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = reducedarray[i][j] - reducedarray[2][j];
                }
            }
            // Multiply array position [3][3] by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'
            for(int i = 3; i < 4; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 3; j < 6; j++) 
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = reducedarray[i][j] * (1.0 / reducedarray[3][3]);
                }
            }    
            // Multiply array position [4][3] by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'
            for(int i = 4; i < 5; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 3; j < 6; j++) 
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = reducedarray[i][j] * (1.0 / reducedarray[4][3]);
                }
            }
            // Subtract the fourth row of the reduced array into the subsequent row 
            for(int i = 4; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 3; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = reducedarray[i][j] - reducedarray[3][j];
                }
            }   
            // Multiply array position [4][4] by its leading coefficient, such that the result is '1'
            for(int i = 4; i <= 4; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 4; j < 6; j++) 
                {
                    reducedarray[i][j] = reducedarray[i][j] * (1.0 / reducedarray[4][4]);
                }
            }     
            // Back solve to assign roots for each row
            for(int i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for(int j = 5; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    roots[i] = reducedarray[4][5];
                    roots[4] = roots[i];
                }
            }
                
            for(int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for(int j = 5; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    roots[i] = reducedarray[3][5] - (reducedarray[3][4] * roots[4]);
                    roots[3] = roots[i];
                }
            }
            
            for(int i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for(int j = 5; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    roots[i] = reducedarray[2][5] - (reducedarray[2][4] * roots[4]) -
                              (reducedarray[2][3] * roots[3]);
                    roots[2] = roots[i];
                }
            }
                    
            for(int i = 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for(int j = 5; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    roots[i] = reducedarray[1][5] - (reducedarray[1][4] * roots[4]) -
                              (reducedarray[1][3] * roots[3]) - (reducedarray[1][2] * roots[2]);
                    roots[1] = roots[i];
                }
            }
            
            for(int i = 0; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for(int j = 5; j >= 0; j--)
                {
            
                
                    roots[i] = reducedarray[0][5] - (reducedarray[0][4] * roots[4]) -
                               (reducedarray[0][3] * roots[3]) - (reducedarray[0][2] * roots[2]) -
                               (reducedarray[0][1] * roots[1]);
                    roots[0] = roots[i];
                }
            }
                            
            writeit(origarray, reducedarray, roots);
        }
        
        void writeit(float origarray[5][6], float reducedarray[5][6], float roots[5])
        {
            cout << "The Original Array" << endl << endl;
            
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    cout << setw(6) << origarray[i][j] << setw(4) << "";
                }
                
                cout << endl << endl;
            }
            
            cout << endl << endl;
            
            cout << "The Reduced Array" << endl << endl;
            
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    cout << setw(6) << reducedarray[i][j] << setw(4) << "";
                }
                
                cout << endl << endl;
            }
            
            cout << endl << endl;
            
            cout << "The Roots of the equations are: " << endl << endl;
            
            cout << setw(6) << "A = " << setw(6) << roots[0] << endl << endl;
            cout << setw(6) << "B = " << setw(6) << roots[1] << endl << endl;
            cout << setw(6) << "C = " << setw(6) << roots[2] << endl << endl;
            cout << setw(6) << "D = " << setw(6) << roots[3] << endl << endl;
            cout << setw(6) << "E = " << setw(6) << roots[4] << endl << endl;
                
            cout << endl << endl;       
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where m=number of columns in matrix and n=number of rows in matrix.
Just the needed segment:

```
void calcit(float origarray[5][6], float reducedarray[5][6])
{
    float roots[5] = {};
    int n=5,m=6;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
            reducedarray[i][j]=origarray[i][j]*(1.0/origarray[i][0]);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            reducedarray[i][j] -=  reducedarray[0][j];
        }
    }
    int num=1;
    for(int i=1;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=num;j<n;j++){
                    for(int k=i;k<m;k++)
            reducedarray[j][k] = reducedarray[j][k] * (1.0 / reducedarray[j][i]);
        }

        for(int j=num+1;j<n;j++){
            for(int k=num;k<m;k++){
                reducedarray[j][k] -= reducedarray[i][k];
            }
        }
        num++;
    }

 for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        float ans=reducedarray[i][m-1];
        for(int j=m-2;j>=i+1;j--){
            ans-=(reducedarray[i][j]*roots[j]);
        }
        roots[i]=ans;
    }
    writeit(origarray, reducedarray, roots);
}
```

Whole code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

// User-defined function declarations (prototypes)
void readit();
void calcit(float[5][6], float[5][6]);
void writeit(float [5][6], float[5][6], float[5]);

// Declaration and definition of the main()
int main()
{
    readit();

    return 0;
}

void readit()
{
    // Local variable declarations
    float origarray[5][6], reducedarray[5][6];

    // Filestream declaration and error tra
        cout << setprecision(4) << endl;
    // File read. 'i' is row index and 'j' is column index.
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            cin >> origarray[i][j];
            reducedarray[i][j] = origarray[i][j];
        }
    }

    calcit(origarray, reducedarray);
}

void calcit(float origarray[5][6], float reducedarray[5][6])
{
    float roots[5] = {};
    int n=5,m=6;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
            reducedarray[i][j]=origarray[i][j]*(1.0/origarray[i][0]);
        }
    }
        for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
                        reducedarray[i][j] -=  reducedarray[0][j];
                }
        }
        int num=1;
    for(int i=1;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=num;j<n;j++){
                    for(int k=i;k<m;k++)
            reducedarray[j][k] = reducedarray[j][k] * (1.0 / reducedarray[j][i]);
        }

        for(int j=num+1;j<n;j++){
            for(int k=num;k<m;k++){
                reducedarray[j][k] -= reducedarray[i][k];
            }
        }
                num++;
    }

for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        float ans=reducedarray[i][m-1];
        for(int j=m-2;j>=i+1;j--){
            ans-=(reducedarray[i][j]*roots[j]);
        }
        roots[i]=ans;
    }
    writeit(origarray, reducedarray, roots);
}

void writeit(float origarray[5][6], float reducedarray[5][6], float roots[5])
{
    cout << "The Original Array" << endl << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(6) << origarray[i][j] << setw(4) << "";
        }

        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "The Reduced Array" << endl << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(6) << reducedarray[i][j] << setw(4) << "";
        }

        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "The Roots of the equations are: " << endl << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<(char)('A'+i)<<" = "<<setw(6)<<roots[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Please, kindly, check if it is working. If it does not work, please notify me in the comments of this post.
Also, i'm not sure why are you using double endl (`cout<<endl<<endl;`),there is an alternative to this: `cout<<"\n\n";` (note that this doesn't flush the output buffer)

Comment: Can you provide what is expected input and output for some testcase? I might be able to help you find the error.

Comment: > 2 -4 6 -8 10 -12
> 8 -2 4 -6 12 -10
 >1 -3     -3 -7  9 -11
>-7  3     -11  5  1  -9
 3 -7 4 -6 9  -5